# python3 module import and installation

Tags: command-line, python3, matplotlib

I'm trying to install matplotlib. This is what I get when I use python3 in terminal. However, in my python file, it still shows that I do not have matplotlib module. :( Why is this?

```
python3
>>> print(matplotlib.__version__)
1.5.2
>>> print(matplotlib.__file__)
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py
```

I tried

```
sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib
```

but nothing changed again. What I get in the terminal when running python3

```
>>> import sys
>>> 'matplotlib' in sys.modules
True
```

but my file still says that it cannot find the module.

Comment: Add this line `#!/usr/bin/env python3` to the top of your file

Comment: it still doesn't work ;(

Comment: try `sudo apt-get build-dep python-matplotlib` And have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605847/how-to-install-matplotlib-with-python3-2

Comment: i already have and it worked only on the terminal, i think. still not wokring for the file though.

Comment: @user65165 How did you install `matplotlib` before you did `sudo apt-get install python3-matplotlib`?

Comment: i did exactly that.

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-matplotlib is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.

Comment: i did what was suggested in the comments here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8605847/how-to-install-matplotlib-with-python3-2 and in other posts. i've tried everything..... i even cloned matplotlib from github in usr/lib/python3/